# Degraded RAID1 on debian 7.5

Tags: linux, debian, raid, hard-drive

I am in a bit of a problem with my root server and a degrading RAID. Unfortunately, I'm no expert when it comes to RAID.

System informations: Debian 7.5, SSD software RAID1, problem occur since a couple of days.

Please see the following infos I could get from the command line:

=======================================================================

```
# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid1] 
md2 : active raid1 sda3[0]
216994240 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]

md1 : active raid1 sda2[0]
523968 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]

md0 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sda1[0]
16768896 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]

unused devices: <none>



# mdadm -D /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Tue Jan  7 09:39:23 2014
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 16768896 (15.99 GiB 17.17 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 16768896 (15.99 GiB 17.17 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Tue Jan  7 10:00:27 2014
          State : clean, degraded 
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : rescue:0
           UUID : 7bda6bfa:f532c676:88921937:c40e5b60
         Events : 19

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
       1       0        0        1      removed




# mdadm -D /dev/md1
/dev/md1:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Tue Jan  7 09:39:23 2014
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 523968 (511.77 MiB 536.54 MB)
  Used Dev Size : 523968 (511.77 MiB 536.54 MB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Mon Jun  9 18:02:08 2014
          State : clean, degraded 
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : rescue:1
           UUID : a34a400c:6e44aebb:e6bd697f:832bebe3
         Events : 106

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        2        0      active sync   /dev/sda2
       1       0        0        1      removed




# mdadm -D /dev/md2
/dev/md2:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Tue Jan  7 09:39:23 2014
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 216994240 (206.94 GiB 222.20 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 216994240 (206.94 GiB 222.20 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Tue Jun 10 11:01:58 2014
          State : clean, degraded 
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : rescue:2
           UUID : fda00d92:d41a6e34:9fcc87f9:29ef44be
         Events : 255477

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        3        0      active sync   /dev/sda3
       1       0        0        1      removed
```

=======================================================================

To my point of view the RAID lost some of its drives? (or all of it!!!)
How can I get this RAID working correct again?
I have a SSH root connection to the server.

Thanks in advance.
chriskapeller

Answer (score 1):

You are indeed correct. The server lost one if it's drives (probably /dev/sdb). You have in total 3 raid devices /dev/md0, /dev/md1, /dev/md2 (i suppose those are for /, /boot and swap)

You need to do the following:

- verify that the disk has indeed failed `dmesg` can help (and confuse you).
- Ask the provider to physically change the failed drive
- After that reassemble the raid

The procedure for raid reassembly is as follows (disks assumed are /dev/sda and /dev/sdb:

- copy disk partitioning from existing disk `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=1M count=1`
- Fix partitioning `cfdisk /dev/sdb` write the partitions basically
- Add the corresponding pieces to the broken array:

  - `mdadm /dev/md0 -add /dev/sda1`
  - `mdadm /dev/md1 -add /dev/sda2`
  - `mdadm /dev/md2 -add /dev/sda3`
- Force filesystem check `fsck`

You can find more info in the following places:

https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Recovering_a_failed_software_RAID

https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_Recovery